# Linq to get common values while grouping DataTable

Tags: vb.net, linq, datatable, dataset

I have DataTable which contains few columns, I would like to group this DT by 1st column, and check if there is common value in other 2 colums. Example

[image]

So i would like to group this table by Col1 ( yes/no ) and check if in those groups is someone from From Col2 who is in both groups if so then add it to the list. This has to be done in LinQ and VB.Net

Comment: Do you care about `Col2` and `Col3` or just `Col2`? When you say "add it to the list", what is "it"?

Comment: @NetMage I care only about Col1 for grouping and Col2 to see if there is common data. "IT" means that I want to get common values from Col2

Comment: Can you do want you want without Linq? Why must this be done with Linq? Is it homework? Homework is fine but you must show the code your tried and explain where it failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code here is in C# and VB.Net.

Using LINQ, you can easily group by `Col1` and then compare the groups. I used `Aggregate` to handle when `Col1` has more values than just `yes` and `no`.

```
var ans = dt.AsEnumerable()
            .GroupBy(r => r.Field<string>("Col1"), r => r.Field<string>("Col2"))
            .Aggregate(default(IEnumerable<string>), (ans, dg) => (ans == null) ? dg : ans.Intersect(dg));
```

In VB.Net, this would be

```
Dim res = dt.AsEnumerable _
            .GroupBy(Function(r) r.Field(Of String)("Col1"), Function(r) r.Field(Of String)("Col2")) _
            .Aggregate(CType(Nothing, IEnumerable(Of String)), Function(ans, dg) If(ans Is Nothing, dg, ans.Intersect(dg)))
```

There are variations that can get return the entire `DataRow` or all matching `DataRow`s but they require creating specialty `IEqualityComparer`s or using much more complicated LINQ expressions with `Where`/`Any`/`Concat` to pull them together.

For example, this returns both matching `DataRow`s for each `Col2` match:

```
var ans =   dt.AsEnumerable()
              .GroupBy(dr => dr.Field<string>("Col1"))
              .Aggregate(default(IEnumerable<DataRow>),
                         (ans, drg) => (ans == null) ? drg
                                                     : ans.Where(ls => drg.Any(dr => dr.Field<string>("Col2") == ls.Field<string>("Col2")))
                                                          .Concat(drg.Where(dr => ans.Any(ls => ls.Field<string>("Col2") == dr.Field<string>("Col2"))))
                        );
```

NOTE: `Intersect` is pretty efficient timewise though it uses extra space to create a simple `Set` from the second collection. The second example is not particularly time or space efficient and would be better done with a custom `IEqualityComparer` and `Intersect`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can convince whoever to not use Linq. From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=netcore-3.1#hashset-and-linq-set-operations

> LINQ provides access to the Distinct, Union, Intersect and Except set
>   operations on any data source that implements the IEnumerable or
>   IQueryable interfaces. HashSet provides a larger and more robust
>   collection of set operations. For example, HashSet provides
>   comparisons such as IsSubsetOf and IsSupersetOf.

I created 2 HashSets and added the data. Then I used the IntersectWith method to alter hsYes to contain only the items that appear in both collections.

```
Private dt As New DataTable

Private Sub FillDataTable()
    dt.Columns.Add("Col1", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("Col2", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("Col3", GetType(String))
    dt.Rows.Add({"yes", "Frank", "LastName1"})
    dt.Rows.Add({"no", "Jessie", "LastName2"})
    dt.Rows.Add({"yes", "Sandra", "LastName3"})
    dt.Rows.Add({"yes", "Jessie", "LastName4"})
    dt.Rows.Add({"yes", "Frank", "LastName5"})
    dt.Rows.Add({"no", "Mike", "LastName6"})
    dt.Rows.Add({"no", "Stefan", "LastName7"})
End Sub

Private Sub GetMatches()
    Dim hsYes As New HashSet(Of String)
    Dim hsNo As New HashSet(Of String)
    For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
        If (dr("Col1").ToString = "yes"Then
            hsYes.Add(dr("Col2").ToString)
        Else
            hsNo.Add(dr("Col2").ToString)) Then
        End If
    Next
    hsYes.IntersectWith(hsNo)
    For Each s In hsYes
        Debug.Print(s) 'Result Jessie
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    FillDataTable()
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    GetMatches()
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Mary, thing is that i know how to do it with For Each :). I was wondering is it possible to create that kind of query in VB using LinQ